# In Swift scroll view delegate is not working

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var scroll: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Wbs: webview!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scroll.backgroundColor=#colorLiteral(red: 0.4392156899, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1)
        scroll.delegate=self
    }
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("as")
    }
}
```

I always wonder I this code is not working, I have implemented scrollViewwillBegin dragging so when I scroll I get the message I didn't get any message , So what wrong here

Comment: Check in story board the settings of the scrollView in terms of allowing scrolling.

Comment: checked still not working?@AlexBailey

Comment: how much content is inside the scrollview? if this is all your code it wont get called as there is no content for a scroll to happen

Comment: that's helpful!! please make it as an answer i will approveit@gmogames

Comment: @gmogames is also correct.  Make sure you set your scroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 800).

Comment: Still its not working@AlexBailey

Comment: i can only able to see  the background color@AlexBailey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrollviews without sufficient content (content size equal or smaller then the scrollview) wont get that delegate called because it has no scroll.

Make sure you have enough content and that all views you add to your scrollview have all 4 of their sides pinned, otherwise it wont work.